# iOS - playing video from remote database

Tags: ios, database, video

Is there a best practice for providing video to an iOS app from a database? For example, should the actual video data be provided from the database to the app or should a URL be return and the actual data access via the URL later by the app?﻿

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the best practice would be to store the video file either on your server or some sort of cloud based storage like s3. Store the url in your database or somewhere that you can access in your app. Then use the url to access the file when it's needed in the app.

As a side note, you might need to look into HTTP Live streaming depending on how your app will be delivering the video. [check this out for more details](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008332-CH102-SW5)